# Firebase auth: Uncaught TypeError: ai(...) is not a function at auth.esm.js:166 after attempting sign in with redirect with multiple firebase apps

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-authentication

I'm using signInWithRedirect(provider) to sign in with google/facebook provider.  After the redirect, I am receiving the error 'Uncaught TypeError: ai(...) is not a function at auth.esm.js:166', followed a few seconds later by a time out error.

This code was working fine when I had a single firebase instance initialized (ie. default).  The only change I have made is that now I am initializing a second firebase instance (firebaseOther), and using this second instance's auth() function for the signInWithRedirect and getRedirectResult, as shown below:

```
firebaseLogin.prototype.loginWithProvider = function(providerName){

var provider;

switch(providerName){

    case "google": 
        provider = new firebase.auth.GoogleAuthProvider(); 
        console.log("provider: ", provider);
        provider.addScope('profile'); 
        provider.addScope('email'); 
    break;
    case "facebook": 
        provider = new firebase.auth.FacebookAuthProvider(); 
        provider.addScope('public_profile'); 
        provider.addScope('email');
    break;
    default: 
        console.log("error: no provider"); 
        return; 
    break;
} 


    firebaseOther.auth().signInWithRedirect(provider);
}

firebaseOther.auth().getRedirectResult().then(function(result) {

      if(result.credential){
          console.log("success"); //no output to the console
      }


  }).catch(function(error) {

      console.log(error.message); // after a few seconds - "The operation has timed out."

  }

});
```

The only similar case I could find to this was here: https://github.com/firebase/firebase-js-sdk/issues/1358

That person's problem was resolved by updating the sdk. I am constrained to using version 5.5.7 because my client's api is already downloading and using that version (that's where the first instance of the firebase app is being initialized).

I suspect the error I'm getting is a result of some sort of conflict between both of the firebase instances being used, but the error message doesnt mean anything to me so I'm completely stuck!  Many thanks.

(edit) I don't know if this could possibly help, but the code the error report is pointing at (auth.esm.js:166) is as follows:

```
function Ci(a) {
    return Di().then(function() {
        return new A(function(b, c) {
            I("gapi.iframes.getContext")().open({
                where: document.body,
                url: a.b,
                messageHandlersFilter: I("gapi.iframes.CROSS_ORIGIN_IFRAMES_FILTER"),
                attributes: {
                    style: {
                        position: "absolute",
                        top: "-100px",
                        width: "1px",
                        height: "1px"
                    }
                },
                dontclear: !0
            }, function(d) {
                function e() {
                    clearTimeout(f);
                    b()
                }
                a.a = d;
                a.a.restyle({
                    setHideOnLeave: !1
                });
                var f = setTimeout(function() {
                    c(Error("Network Error"))
                }, Ei.get());
                d.ping(e).then(e, function() {
                    c(Error("Network Error"))
                })
            })
        })
    })
}
```

Comment: I am experiencing the same issue. I have removed all Form DOMs to normal Divs but still no luck.